# CodeIgniter and IonAuth 'If user is logged in'

Tags: php, codeigniter, ion-auth

I'm currently working on a CodeIgniter and IonAuth project and I have encountered this problem.

Scenario: When I login, I can still access the login page. What I want to do is to remove this access because the user is already logged in.

this is my index method in my auth class:

```
function index(){

        if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in())
        {
            //redirect them to the login page
            redirect('auth/login', 'refresh');
        }
        elseif($this->ion_auth->logged_in())
        {
            //redirect them to the index page if logged in
            redirect('/', 'refresh');
        }
        elseif (!$this->ion_auth->is_admin())
        {
            //redirect them to the home page because they must be an administrator to view this
            redirect($this->config->item('base_url'), 'refresh');
        }
}
```

Any ideas would be awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open up the auth controller. Go down to the login method. Add the following lines at the top:

```
if($this->ion_auth->logged_in())
{
    //redirect them to the index page if logged in
    redirect('/', 'refresh');
}
```

Also, the auth controller that comes with Ion_auth is really just an example and should be used as a reference. Be sure to read all relevant documentation.

- https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/welcome.html
- http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/

**Edit**: Do note that using 'refresh' for redirects has its uses but is probably not necessary in this situation. Here's info on that:

- https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'll check on this ASAP!